# angularjs How to create stack of divs with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In short I have a list of div created with ng-repeat.

```
<div class="col-md-2-4" ng-repeat="card in cards">
    <ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
       <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in card.cardItem">
          <div class="pull-left">
            {{value.keys}}
          </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Which display something like this: **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mYxXW6abUxqX47Xe4Sek?p=preview)**

But is this possible to make them stacked something like this? :
[image]

I guess I have to dynamically set the positions and z-index for each div. But I'm  not sure if this can be even possible and if so then how? This will be great if there is any solution for this.

If need jQuery/js it will be fine too.

Comment: Which one is on top: the first or last?

Comment: First one should go on the top :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can make divs position absolute relatively to container and then use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2-4" 
     ng-repeat="card in cards.reverse()" 
     ng-style="{left: 2 * $index + 'px', top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
    <ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
        <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in card.cardItem">
            <div class="pull-left">
                {{value.keys}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the key here is ngStyle expression:

```
ng-style="{left: 2 * $index + 'px', top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}"
```

especially `z-index` part.

**Demo 1:** http://plnkr.co/edit/aDlptsf9JY1nYhEJpaVu?p=preview

**Demo 2:** Here is a demo from follow-up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564383/angularjs-click-button-to-show-next-previous-div) with nice add/remove cards animations :)

http://plnkr.co/edit/tLVJrpqavKbHvKzMljNG?p=preview

Comment: Is this possible for you to help me on this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564383/angularjs-click-button-to-show-next-previous-div?noredirect=1#comment47278857_29564383

This is the extended version of your solution.

Comment: Do you think it's (above link ) doable ?

Answer (score 2):

The following would repeat across a list of cards, increase the z-index,top, and left all by 1 for each iteration, using $index as the reference for place of the current cards. Depending on how your cards need to be laid out, you may needs to do some `cards.length - $index` stuff to reverse it.

```
<div 
    ng-repeat="card in cards" 
    style="position:absolute" 
    ng-style="{'z-index':$index; 'top':$index+'px';'left':$index+'px'}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines should do what you want.

```html
<div class="col-md-2-4" ng-repeat="card in cards" style="position: absolute; top:{{$index}}px; left:{{$index}}px; z-index: -{{$index}};">
    <ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
       <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in card.cardItem">
          <div class="pull-left">
            {{value.keys}}
          </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-style` directive and the `$index` variable in conjuction:

```
<div class="col-md-2-4" ng-repeat="card in cards" ng-style="{'z-index': $index}">
    <ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
       <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in card.cardItem">
          <div class="pull-left">
            {{value.keys}}
          </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Which will make the z-index increment by 1 as you go down starting from 0.

Comment: But it's not the li one, it should be the content of it
 <div class="col-md-2-4" ng-repeat="card in cards">

Comment: My bad. The concept is still the same regardless