# angularjs Click button to show next / previous div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a stack of Divs created with ng-repeat. **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWQ95KE2qpr6BAHWmsna?p=preview)**

Quick Image:

[image]

Is it possible to create this stack of div work like a slider? Like:

- if I press Next button Top div will slide away and 2nd top will show.
- pressing Previous button will show previous div if there any.

**Code:**

```
<div class="col-md-2-4" 
     ng-repeat="card in cards" 
     ng-style="{left: 2 * $index + 'px', top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
<ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
   <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in card.cardItem">
     <div class="pull-left">
          {{value.keys}}
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="keys">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-pre">Previous</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
</div>
```

It will really help me if this is possible.

Comment: My suggestions for this (for performance and your own sanity), separate the display behaviour into a style file and just use classes for the slide effect. So, you can add a class like `.active` to the current div and remove it when the next is called. So, when removing a class, you can trigger the effect but not have it rely on your JS. Remember, JS for logic, CSS for styling (and wisdom for differentiating the two).

Comment: *"slide away"* and disappear?

Comment: Yes ! it will disappear :)

Comment: Okay. So the card disappeared. Then you press previous. What happens? It reappear from nowhere or what?

Comment: Ok  it will hide when you press next. Then if you press previous it will show  up again. Just it will be in a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this is fun. Here is how you can do it. By clicking buttons lets calculate the index of the new top card. Anything with the index lower then new calculated one should be hidden. In order to hide card with nice animations it's optimal to use CSS classes with arbitrary transition rules.

As the result HTML will look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2-4" 
    ng-class="{'card-hide': index  > $index + 1}"
    ng-repeat="card in cards" 
    ng-style="{left: 2 * $index + 'px', top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">

    <ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
        <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in card.cardItem">
            <div class="pull-left">
                {{value.keys}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="keys">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" ng-click="index = index < cards.length ? index + 1 : cards.length">Next</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" ng-click="index = index > 1 ? index - 1 : 1">Previous</button>
</div>
```

where starting index is defined in controller as:

```
$scope.index = 1;
```

Slide/fade effect is handled by very simple CSS rule:

```
.card-hide {
    left: -100px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tLVJrpqavKbHvKzMljNG?p=preview

Comment: Demo link is the old one I guess ! But I implemented above one and working perfectly. But Now I feel sad that I don't have much knowledge on pure programming :( I need to learn lot more. 

I don't want to say just thank you. This is way more then that. But I realize I need to have more better understanding on programming. Any suggestion from you will be blessing for me :)

Comment: Yea, I updated the link. Don't be sad, we are all learning. No one knows everything, and the more you try and practice the quicker you become better programmer. It's not easy but it's very rewarding - so it's all up to you.  And at the same time it's not that hard - you just need to learn every day. Good luck!

Comment: Hi , I see you added {{index}} to display index number. 
Is this possible to display how many divs are remaining ?
I added a delete button also which removes the top div on each click :
http://plnkr.co/edit/HZtqmzqVgPKkh94SOfR2?p=preview

Comment: Try `cards.length - ($index - 1)`: http://plnkr.co/edit/v07ek5hQsfgAdSMqnLXu?p=preview

Comment: Sorry I need one last help with this :(
I need to show different title for this different divs. I updated the card array and added a new section for adding titles. But not sure how to relate them. Currently all title are showing. Thanks a lot for all the help you did : http://plnkr.co/edit/WpJUMDMxFzpuCWAm5uHR?p=preview

Comment: I was trying something like this: {{cards[index].titles}} . What this index-1 do ? it reverse the array ? Anyway Thanks again

Comment: It's just you `index` is +1 to the real array item index.