# Angularjs switching divs with next and previous with json content

Tags: html, angularjs

I have made a plunker of my code so far. The problem is i want each question to be in the div and by clicking the next i want to go to the next question. Also i have a set of images for each question which i would want to change everytime the user clicks to go to the next question. Right now it doesnt seem to be showing all the questions just the last one which is question number 10. Please help  me...

```
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.questions = []
       $http.get('results.json').success(function(data) {
          angular.forEach(data, function(question) {
              $scope.questions.push(question);
    }) 
  });
       $scope.index = 1;
 }]);
```

I have used the code suggested here : [angularjs Click button to show next / previous div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564383/angularjs-click-button-to-show-next-previous-div)

Here is my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/DqNRnc8xYZn73vdkWjaG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues here:

1. Change the ng-class expression to: {'div-hide': index  != $index + 1}
2. The ng-click has a wrong spacing around the word "index" (e.g ng-click="index=i ndex)

Fixing these two seems to work..

Comment: Oh gosh i just noticed that! Thankyou very much its working now !

Comment: Cool happy to help. Please mark the answer if it is working for you ;)