# Stacks of div's angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to re-make this post:
[angularjs How to create stack of divs with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523533/angularjs-how-to-create-stack-of-divs-with-ng-repeat)

which is an angular1 code into angular2/3 version.
However, i am stucked at one part only, where:

```
ng-class="{'card-hide': index  > $index + 1}"
```

does not work. I am making it as: `[ngClass]="{'card-hide': index  > $index + 1}"` but that `$index` is not valid. They have a plunker provided here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tLVJrpqavKbHvKzMljNG?p=preview

And I see in app.js that they use $scope.index = 1;

I have tried `[ngClass]="{'card-hide': index  > index + 1}"` but not working too. I need to add this class `card-hide` to the very last element from the ngFor list, every time I click a button or call a function to remove the element. So, this class should be added only in the last element from the list and removed if you go back. The plunker has everything explained, just written in Angular1

Comment: That's what i am doing and its fine. It's just that the part of adding this class to the last element on the list, does not work. They have two buttons, prev and next like this: <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" (click)="idx = idx < list.length ? idx + 1 : list.length">Next</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" (click)="idx = idx > 1 ? idx - 1 : 1">Previous</button>

Comment: There is also a `last` property you can use: `*ngFor="let item of items; let last = last"`, so you can then do `ng-class="{'card-hide': last}"`

Comment: I see, thanks. But, it will not work in this logic, as each time the index is changed, this must be added to the last element in the list. See their plunker again: http://plnkr.co/edit/tLVJrpqavKbHvKzMljNG?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't had a proper look at the plunkr. I understand the issue now, take a look at the answer below. I've added a Stackblitz so you can see it in action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, `$index` is referring to the index of the individual card. We can do that using the following:

```
*ngFor="let card of cards; let $index = index"
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j6gx8y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: I have one more thing that i want to implement and it's blocking me. I want basically to limit the stacking so it shows 3-4 stacked elements. All the new elements will be added to the list, but they will not change the top position. I have put this: [ngStyle]= "{top: cards.length < 4 ? this.spaceOne * $index + 'px' : this.spaceTwo, 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}"> , where I have the spaceOne=2 and SpaceTwo=0 in the TS file, but right after the list lenght changes to 4, it applies this rule to all of the elements so they all change the top=0 position